# C# and mysql, tables join

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Now I am working on a C# soft which use a lot SQL database.. the problem is I am not very friend with SQL ...

So, I have 3 tables

tab1:

```
ID| Ingrediente| Cant_disponibila
1 | mere | 250
2 | pere | 14
3 | nuci | 111
```

tab2:

```
ID_Recipe| Denumire
1        |  mere
2        |  pere
3        |  nuci
```

tab3:

```
ID| Recipe_ID |Ingrediente_ID | Cant_necesara
1 | 1 | 7 | 250
2 | 1 | 5 | 14
3 | 2 | 6 | 111
4 | 2 | 1 | 111
5 | 2 | 2 | 111
```

I need to make the next task:cant_disponibila=cant_disponibila - cant_necesara ....."-" means substract :)
all these if denumire="something";

later edit : query in mysql is this:

```
UPDATE tab1 JOIN tab3 ON (ID = Ingrediente_ID) JOIN tab2 ON (ID_Recipe = Recipe_ID) SET Cant_disponibila = Cant_disponibila - Cant_necesara WHERE Denumire = "...";
```

the problem is that in my c# software is giving me an error which says "incorect syntax near the keyword join"

Comment: Your set clause has to come before your join clause.  Also, you need the keyword "from".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `SQL Server` and not `MySQL` based on your syntax error message, here's an `UPDATE` statement with join for `SQL Server`

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.Cant_disponibila = a.Cant_disponibila - c.Cant_necesara 
FROM    tab1 a
        INNER JOIN tab3 c
            ON a.ID = c.Ingrediente_ID
        INNER JOIN tab2 b
            ON b.ID_Recipe = c.Recipe_ID 
WHERE   b.Denumire = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track I just think you need to re-order the syntax a little bit like so:

```
UPDATE tab1 
SET Cant_disponibila = Cant_disponibila - Cant_necesara
FROM tab1 
JOIN tab3 ON (ID = Ingrediente_ID) 
JOIN tab2 ON (ID_Recipe = Recipe_ID)  WHERE Denumire = "...";
```